# The image is loading correctly, but it fails to change when using javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, image

```
<img id="myImg" src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&amp;id=1gsRqRNoKabIkK9z1NhioUhpFOgIKww5Q" width="107" height="98">

<button onclick="change_image()">Change Image</button>
<script>
function change_image() {
  document.getElementById("myImg").src = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&amp;id=1gsRqRNoKabIkK9z1NhioUhpFOgIKww5Q";
}
</script>
```

Image from the same link is loading properly. But it fails to change when using a js function

Answer (score 2):

`&amp;` is how you represent a `&` character in HTML.

It **isn't** how you represent one in JavaScript (not even JS in a `<script>` element in an HTML document as `<script>` elements are defined so that [normal HTML parsing](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#data-state) rules (where `&` would switch to the *character reference state*) are [suspended](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#script-data-state)).

The URL is getting a 400 error.

In the JS use only `&` without the `amp;`.